# Scala: type hint for lambda

Tags: scala, generics, lambda, scala-java-interop

I'm refreshing scala. This looks very simple to me but I can't get it to run:

```
import java.nio.file.{FileSystems, Files}

object ScalaHello extends App {
    val dir = FileSystems.getDefault.getPath("/home/intelli/workspace")
    Files.walk(dir).map(_.toFile).forEach(println)
}
```

It throws error at the mapping lambda:

```
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : java.util.function.Function[java.nio.file.Path,java.io.File]
 required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: java.nio.file.Path, _ <: ?R]
```

I suspect it has something to do with providing type hints for the lambda but I can't find anything surfing Google. Much appreciated

Comment: What is your Scala version? What is your Java version?

Comment: And also please show your build file (`build.sbt`?). Especially `scalacOptions`.

Comment: Does anything change for you if you specify `.map[File]((_: Path).toFile)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `Files.walk` returns a Java `Stream`, so `map` and `forEach` come from Java.

Assuming you are using Scala 2.12, your code will work if you either:

1. Update Scala version to 2.13 (no need to make any other changes in this case)
2. Specify return type of `map`:

```scala
Files.walk(dir).map[File](_.toFile).forEach(println)
```

3. Convert to Scala collections before calling `map`:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
Files.walk(dir).iterator().asScala.map(_.toFile).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Cool. So it seems to be 2.12

Comment: Kolmar, thanks for the explanation: I somehow assumed that the stages of Scala streams would apply directly ...but as you explain, I was applying the transformations from Java streams!

Comment: @Kolmar *"2.13 (no need to make any other changes in this case)"* This seems to depend on `scalacOptions` sometimes. With `-Ydelambdafy:inline` `.forEach(println)` doesn't compile in 2.13 (`class type required but java.util.function.Consumer[_ >: java.io.File] found`) while `.forEach(println(_))` does. With `-Ydelambdafy:method` (default) `.forEach(println)` compiles.